# Blazor Service calls returns connection errors occasionally

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am getting this error occasionally from  a Blazor server side .NET Core project.

> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
> connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

After reload the page or retry to execute same function call one more time there will be no errors and results will be returned

The DbContext definition looks like below:

```
public class ADPortalDbContext:DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

   public ADPortalDbContext(DbContextOptions<ADPortalDbContext> options)
      : base(options) { }
 }
```

The Service for returning the results from database looks like below:

public class CompanyService : ICompanyService
{
private readonly ADPortalDbContext context;

```
public CompanyService(ADPortalDbContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<Company>> GetCompaniesSearchText(string searchText)
{
    try
    {
        return await context.Companies
            .Where(i => EF.Functions.Like(i.Name.ToLower(), $"%{searchText.ToLower()}%"))
            .ToListAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to return results " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs of Blazor app is like below:

```
 services.AddTransient<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();
 services.AddDbContext<ADPortalDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseMySql(connStr, srvVersion, x =>
                    {
                        x.MigrationsAssembly("DCPortal.Infrastructre");
                    }),
                    contextLifetime: ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

The Blazor page calling the service is like below:

```
@inject ICompanyService  CompanyService

private async Task<IEnumerable<Company>> SearchCompanies(string searchText)
{
try
{
    IEnumerable<Company> companies_ListDb = await CompanyService.GetCompaniesSearchText(searchText);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     //Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
}
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue - implementing an `IDbContextFactory` solved it for me.

Comment: @AndrewCorrigan Can you share some resources or useful links on how to implement the same?

Comment: @Sebastian https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/ If you scroll down a bit the documents will talk about implementing a DbContextFactory.

Comment: Was just typing out the answer @Sebastian

Comment: @Sebastian the problem *and* the solution is documented in [ASP.NET Core Blazor Server with Entity Framework Core (EFCore)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-6.0). The problem is that the scope in a Blazor Server application is essentially the user session (the circuit) so if you try to use a scoped DbContext you'll end up using the same instance over and over. The solution shown in the docs is to use a DbContextFactory instead and construct a new DbContext instance when needed, and dispose it immediately after use

Comment: @panagiotis I am struggling to make it work with services. I am not using dbcontext directly inside my blazor pages instead via a service I am accessing dbcontext

Answer (score 1):

The general crux of the issue is the lifetime of the service - a DB context should be pretty much single-use; so in the background the connection is being closed at some point (resulting in your error).

The only real way I've found to get around it is to implement a context factory.

So, in your case, you'll want to create a file in the same area as your context:

```
public class ADPortalDbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory<ADPortalDbContext>
{
    private readonly DbContextOptions<ADPortalDbContext> options;

    public ADPortalDbContextFactory(DbContextOptions<ADPortalDbContext> contextOptions)
    {
        options = contextOptions;
    }

    public ADPortalDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        return new ADPortalDbContext(options);
    }
}
```

From there, you can put a simple tweak into your startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<ADPortalDbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseMySql(connStr, srvVersion, x =>
                    {
                        x.MigrationsAssembly("DCPortal.Infrastructre");
                    }));
services.AddDbContextFactory<ADPortalDbContext, ADPortalDbContextFactory>(options =>
                    options.UseMySql(connStr, srvVersion, x =>
                    {
                        x.MigrationsAssembly("DCPortal.Infrastructre");
                    }), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);
services.AddScoped<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();
```

Your service then becomes:

```
public class CompanyService : ICompanyService 
{ 
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<ADPortalDbContext> contextFactory;
    
    public CompanyService(IDbContextFactory<ADPortalDbContext> context)
    {
        this.contextFactory = context;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Company>> GetCompaniesSearchText(string searchText)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var context = contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
            {
                return await context.Companies
                    .Where(i => EF.Functions.Like(i.Name.ToLower(), $"%{searchText.ToLower()}%"))
                    .ToListAsync()
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unable to return results " + ex.Message);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: contextFactory does not contain a definition for AddDbContext Instead i am getting an option CreateDbContext Are they the same?

Comment: CreateDbContext is correct - I'd made a typo, just edited it

Comment: Also do we need to apply Lifetime to the startup Something like belowservices.AddDbContextFactory<ADPortalDbContext, ADPortalDbContextFactory>(options =>
                    options.UseMySql(connStr, srvVersion, x =>
                    {
                        x.MigrationsAssembly("DCPortal.Infrastructre");
                    }),
                     ServiceLifetime.Transient);  I was getting error  without that like below System.AggregateException: 
'Some services are not able to be constructed 
(Error while validating the service descriptor
 'ServiceType:

Comment: System.AggregateException: 
'Some services are not able to be constructed 
(Error while validating the service descriptor
 'ServiceType: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1
   Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType:
--.ADPortalDbContextFactory': Cannot consume scoped service 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1
--.Infrastructre.Data.ADPortalDbContext]' from singleton
. 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think it defaults to setting the DbContext to scoped and the DbContextFactory to singleton (thinking about it, in my system I've set this to Scoped).

Comment: I set Scoped and still Service is causing exceptions Messaeg: Failed to load result set 
InnerException : Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..

Comment: Only thing I can think of is setting multiple active results sets to true in the connection string then. Or maybe increasing the timeout values